# Use layout function within levelplot

Tags: r, levelplot

I am doing mapping in R and found the very useful `levelplot` function in `rasterVis` package. I will like to display multiple plots in a window. However, `par(mfcol)` does not fit within `lattice`. I found `layout` function very useful in my case but it fails to perform what I want to do.

Here is my code:

```
s <- stack(Precip_DJF1, Precip_DJF2, Precip_DJF3, Precip_DJF4, 
           Precip_DJF5, Precip_DJF6)

levelplot(s, layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5), 2, 3)), 
          at=seq(floor(3.81393), ceiling(23.06363), length.out=20), 
          par.settings=themes, par.strip.text=list(cex=0), 
          scales=list(alternating=FALSE))
```

Using

```
 layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5), 2, 3))
```

fails while `layout(3, 2)` works but the plots are displayed row-wise instead of column-wise. I want the plots to be displayed in column 1, then column 2 etc. Something like:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 2, 3)

> mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    5
# [2,]    2    4    6
```

Is there a function within `levelplot` or `lattice` to do this kind of layout?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Through `index.cond` option, maybe.

Comment: It would be helpful if you actually included some sample input data to make the problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It also seems like you're confusing the `layout()` function which is used for base graphics with the `layout=` parameter which is used with Lattice plots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by @Pascal, you can use `index.cond` to do this:

For example:

```
library(rasterVis)
s <- stack(replicate(6, raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))))
levelplot(s, layout=c(3, 2), index.cond=list(c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)))
```

[image]

If you don't want to hard-code the list passed to `index.cond`, you can use something like:

```
index.cond=list(c(matrix(1:nlayers(s), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)))
```

where the `2` indicates the number of rows you will have in your layout.

---

Of course you could also pass a `stack` with layers arranged in the desired row-wise plotting order, e.g.:

```
levelplot(s[[c(matrix(1:nlayers(s), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE))]], layout=c(3, 2))
```