# Odd Number plots using levelplot and rasterVis

Tags: layout, plot, raster, levelplot, rastervis

I'm using the `rasterVis` package and the `levelplot` function to plot seven rasters on a single plot.

Here is the layout I'm going for: 
[correct layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo1NW.png)

I've achieved this using the following code:

```
png("E:/all_files/production/plots/for_final/hist_vis_split2.png", 
width=6, height=9, units="in", res=72)
layout(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 4, 2, byrow = T))
print(maurer+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(2,1,3,4), more=TRUE)
print(nar.ccsm+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(1,2,3,4), more=TRUE)
print(nar.gfdl+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(3,2,3,4), more=TRUE)
print(bcsd.ccsm+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(1,3,3,4), more=TRUE)
print(bcsd.gfdl+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(3,3,3,4), more=TRUE)
print(bcca.ccsm+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(1,4,3,4), more=TRUE)
print(bcca.gfdl+layer(sp.lines(sr)), split=c(3,4,3,4))
dev.off()
```

Besides being clunky and lacking control, this is still missing a main title and a single common `colorkey` for the entire image.

I would prefer to use the `levelplot` command. Below is the code I've used to plot all seven rasters in a single `levelplot` with a single `colorkey`. Unfortunately this does not have the correct layout:

[incorrect layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Itju.png)

```
crop.stack <- stack(maurer, bcsd.ccsm.crop, bcsd.gfdl.crop, bcca.ccsm.crop, 
                bcca.gfdl.crop, nar.ccsm.crop, nar.gfdl.crop)
plot.names <- c("Maurer", "BCSD CCSM", "BCSD GFDL", "BCCA CCSM", 
            "BCCA GFDL", "NARCCAP CCSM", "NARCCAP GFDL")

png("E:/all_files/production/plots/for_final/hist_vis.png", 
    width=6, height=9, units="in", res=72)
hist <- levelplot(crop.stack, main="Historical Average Production Days", 
          col.regions=cols, 
          names.attr=plot.names, 
          scales=list(draw=F), 
          layout=c(2,4))
hist + layer(sp.lines(sr))
dev.off()
```

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28621120/use-layout-function-within-levelplot) is close, but does not deal with and odd number of plots. How can I achieve the desired layout within the `levelplot` command?

Comment: Might be worth checking out `gridExtra::grid.arrange`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html